How to simplify Leaflet's focusing if I need any combination of latLng and bounds?
I keep struggling with keeping track of center (with zoom) and bounds in parallel while (re)combining them as I collect further markers and shape bounds to focus on map.
What I wish is to have a single object like centerOrBounds, which I can extend by any number of latLng, e.g. centerOrBounds.addLatLng(latLng) and bounds e.g. centerOrBounds.addBouns(bounds) and finally: centerOrBounds.getFocusedOn(map). See and try the code below which I’m using in my solution.
I haven’t found an out of the box solution for my problem yet and have the feeling like reinventing the wheel. Is there a solution to my problem that I might have missed?
Or is there a better way to handle combining bounds and lat/lng inputs for focusing a map in Leaflet?
The problem is, that bounds vs center is logically different stuff, with accordingly different handling - either: map.setView(center, zoom), or map.fitBounds(bounds) and fitBounds currently cannot handle bounds with just 1 coordinate, or 2 identical coordinates.
On some events, e.g. on shape or marker editing in the map I need to recollect my centerOrBounds.
(I need this in plain HTML/JavaScript/CSS page environ of my django-leaflet project.)


// Initialize the map
var map = L.map('map');

// Add OpenStreetMap tile layer
var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

class MapFocusManager {
    constructor(initialZoom = 15) {
        this.bounds = L.latLngBounds();
        this.standaloneCoords = undefined;
        this.initialZoom = initialZoom;
    }

    addBounds(bounds) {
        if (bounds && bounds instanceof L.LatLngBounds && bounds.isValid()) {
            // fill bounds property for the first time if empty or just extend it if already filled:
            this.bounds.extend(bounds);
            if (this.standaloneCoords) {
                // if there was just standaloneCoords before, integrate it in bounds and clear it:
                this.bounds.extend(this.standaloneCoords);
                this.standaloneCoords = undefined;
            }
        }
    }

    addLatLng(latLng) {
        if (latLng) {
            if (Array.isArray(latLng) && latLng.length === 2) {
                // try to redirect - relying on: L.LatLng
                this.addLatLng(L.latLng(latLng[0], latLng[1]));
            } else if (latLng instanceof L.LatLng) {
                if (this.standaloneCoords) {
                    // Combine the stored standaloneCoords with latLng to bounds and empty it:
                    this.bounds.extend([this.standaloneCoords, [latLng.lat, latLng.lng]]);
                    this.standaloneCoords = undefined;
                } else if (this.bounds.isValid()) {
                    // simply extend bounds it if already filled:
                    this.bounds.extend(latLng);
                } else {
                // entering 1st coords in an onw empty state:
                    this.standaloneCoords = [latLng.lat, latLng.lng];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    addLatLngArray(latLngArray) {
        if (latLngArray && Array.isArray(latLngArray) &&
            latLngArray.length > 0 && Array.isArray(latLngArray[0])
        ) {
            latLngArray.forEach(coords => this.addLatLng(coords));
        }
    }

    addCoordinates(lat, lng) {
        this.addLatLng(L.latLng(lat, lng));
    }

    addMapFocusManager(manager) {
        if (!manager) return;
        if (!(manager instanceof MapFocusManager)) {
            throw new Error('MapFocusManager must be provided.');
        }

        if (manager.bounds.isValid()) {
            this.addBounds(manager.bounds);
        }
        if (manager.standaloneCoords) {
            this.addLatLng(manager.standaloneCoords);
        }
    }

    clone() {
        const clonedManager = new MapFocusManager(this.initialZoom);
        if (this.bounds.isValid()) {
            clonedManager.addBounds(this.bounds);
        }
        if (this.standaloneCoords) {
            clonedManager.addLatLng(this.standaloneCoords);
        }
        return clonedManager;
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return !this.bounds.isValid() && !this.standaloneCoords;
    }

    focusMapTo(map) {
        if (!map) {
            throw new Error('Map must be provided to focus.');
        }

        const currentTileLayerMaxZoom = mapGetCurrentTileLayerMaxZoom(map);

        if (this.bounds.isValid()) {
            console.log(`focusMapTo: fitBounds: currentTileLayerMaxZoom: ${currentTileLayerMaxZoom}`, this);
            map.fitBounds(this.bounds, currentTileLayerMaxZoom ? { maxZoom: currentTileLayerMaxZoom } : undefined);
        } else if (this.standaloneCoords) {
            const finalZoom = Math.min(this.initialZoom, currentTileLayerMaxZoom ?? this.initialZoom);
            console.log(`focusMapTo: setView: ${this.initialZoom}, currentTileLayerMaxZoom: ${currentTileLayerMaxZoom}, finalZoom: ${finalZoom}`, this);
            map.setView(this.standaloneCoords, finalZoom);
        }
    }

    static create(input = null, initialZoom = 15) {
        let manager = new MapFocusManager(initialZoom);

        if (!input) {
            return manager;
        }

        if (Array.isArray(input)) {
            if (input.length === 2 && typeof input[0] === 'number' && typeof input[1] === 'number') {
                manager.addLatLng(input);
            } else {
                manager.addLatLngArray(input);
            }
        } else if (input instanceof L.LatLngBounds) {
            manager.addBounds(input);
        } else if (input instanceof L.LatLng) {
            manager.addLatLng(input);
        }

        return manager;
    }
}

const mapGetCurrentTileLayerMaxZoom = function(map, fallbackMaxZoom = 20) {
    if (!map) {
        throw new Error('Map must be provided to get currentTileLayerMaxZoom.');
    }

    let maxTileLayerZoom = undefined;

    // Find the current tile layer and extract the maxZoom if available
    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.TileLayer && layer.options.maxZoom) {
            maxTileLayerZoom = layer.options.maxZoom;
            console.log(`mapGetCurrentTileLayerMaxZoom: found L.TileLayer with maxTileLayerZoom: ${maxTileLayerZoom}`, layer);
        }
    });

    return maxTileLayerZoom ?? fallbackMaxZoom;
};

// Example usage:
var latLngCoords1 = [49.603630, 10.158256];
var latLngCoords2 = [49.613928, 10.179981];
var latLngCoords3 = [49.619242, 10.187804];
var latLngCoords4 = [49.626327, 10.143388];
var latLngCoords5 = [49.621538, 10.15684];

L.marker(latLngCoords1).addTo(map).bindTooltip(`<b>Map Manager 1</b><br/>Initial center: ${latLngCoords1}<br/>Initial zoom: 17`);
L.marker(latLngCoords2).addTo(map).bindTooltip(`<b>Map Manager 2</b><br/>Bouds:  <i>South West</i><br/>${latLngCoords2}`);
L.marker(latLngCoords3).addTo(map).bindTooltip(`<b>Map Manager 2</b><br/>Bouds:  <i>North East</i><br/>${latLngCoords3}`);
L.marker(latLngCoords4).addTo(map).bindTooltip(`<b>Map Manager 3</b><br/>LatLng: <i>North West</i><br/>${latLngCoords4}`);
L.marker(latLngCoords5).addTo(map).bindTooltip(`<b>Map Manager 3</b><br/>LatLng: <i>South East</i><br/>${latLngCoords5}`);

var latLngArrayX1 = [latLngCoords2, latLngCoords3];
var initialBounds = L.latLngBounds(latLngArrayX1);

var latLngArrayX2 = [latLngCoords4, latLngCoords5];

var mapFocusManager1 = MapFocusManager.create(latLngCoords1, 17);
var mapFocusManager2 = MapFocusManager.create(initialBounds, 14);
var mapFocusManager3 = MapFocusManager.create(latLngArrayX2);

// Clone mapFocusManager1
var clonedMapFocusManager = mapFocusManager1.clone();

// Add mapFocusManager2 into mapFocusManager3
clonedMapFocusManager.addMapFocusManager(mapFocusManager2);
clonedMapFocusManager.addMapFocusManager(mapFocusManager3);

mapFocusManager1.focusMapTo(map);
#map {
    height: calc(65vh);
    width: 100%;
}
.btn-container {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Leaflet Map Focus Manager</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Leaflet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">Leaflet Map with Focus Manager</h1>
                <div id="map"></div>
                <div class="btn-container">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mapFocusManager1.focusMapTo(map)">Focus Map Manager 1</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="mapFocusManager2.focusMapTo(map)">Focus Map Manager 2</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="mapFocusManager3.focusMapTo(map)">Focus Map Manager 3</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="clonedMapFocusManager.focusMapTo(map)">Clone Mngr 1 &amp; Add Mngr 2 &amp; 3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap 5 JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Leaflet JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



